# Kafka Connect Splunk Sink Connector Issue

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, splunk

I am running into another issue with Splunk sink connector. When I use

```
"splunk.hec.ssl.validate.certs": "true"
```

the error I get is -

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target

When I use `"splunk.hec.ssl.validate.certs": "false"` the error becomes -

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   java.security.cert.CertificateException: Certificates do not conform
>   to algorithm constraints Caused by:
>   java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Algorithm constraints
>   check failed on keysize limits. RSA 1024bit key used with
>   certificate........

Any idea what is causing it ?

Comment: `Certificates do not conform to algorithm constraints`... Well, how did you create the certificates?

Comment: Hi @cricket_007, on the Splunk server the certificate is company provided one.

Comment: I mean on the Kafka Connect JVM process

Comment: Hi @cricket_007, same thing, provided by company.

Comment: Hi @cricket_007, it turns out the Splunk server had bad certificate. Once we pointed to Splunk production , it worked. Had a question on jdbc sink connector. I don't find connect-distributed.sh file on connect server. I see it on the broker server. Is that an issue ? Because my understanding is we need that file and the connect-distributed.properties and properties file of worker to run it.

Comment: That file is provided by all Kafka downloads. There is no separate installation for Kafka Connect servers, only the process that starts (note: not saying you run on the same machine)

Comment: some details about the certificates used by Splunk Connect for Kafka here http://isbyr.com/splunk-connect-for-kafka/#:~:text=storage.partitions%20properties-,Hardening,-Let%E2%80%99s%20talk%20a